# My question got down voted

Tags: support

I am new to the Hinduism stack exchange site and i would like to understand the reason for my question getting downvoted, [Why are women not allowed say gayatri mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/why-are-women-not-allowed-to-say-gayatri-mantra). This would help me to post my questions/answer better. Also the tag for this questions is changed to superstitions not sure if it can be tagged to superstition.

Comment: I think your question is absolutely fine and I don't think the superstition tag should have been added, so I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

As far as the question is concerned, it's absolutely fine. So there is nothing for you to worry.

Why people down vote is extremely subjective in nature. If I go into their shoes, I may down vote your specific question for following reasons:

- Asking a sexist question, which differentiate Man vs Woman
- Clarity lacking in the question; e.g. *"**Many say** that girls/women 
  are not supposed to chant..."*; Either you should have given solid
  references to this claim or you should ask simply "Can women chant
  Mantra..."
- Some people may find this question itself of no importance

Anyways, your question was good and I had upvoted it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you see a downvote, ask 'why the downvote?' in comments under the question (or the answer, if you answered a question) so the person who downvoted can answer you why, right there. Problem with asking it here is that whoever downvoted you may not be reading your question here in meta.

Also, see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes#comment313_135) under [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) which has been upvoted by many.

Comment: But i think now we can not really post "Why the downvote?" kind of comments.. People are flagging them and getting rid of them if found..