# Banned from asking questions

Tags: support

I have a question about my Hinduism Stack Exchange post: [Is having sex with a woman not married according to Hindu marriage ceremonies, parastreegamana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/is-having-sex-with-a-woman-not-married-according-to-hindu-marriage-ceremonies-p)

I keep receiving strange notifications, I don't know to what it belongs to. Earlier in the day I was informed that I got -8 for this question, later on I received +4 in notification bar, but I don't know for what I received those. After that I received +3 in notification bar, even for this I didn't know to which blog post it belonged. Now I log in I see a red notification and when I click on it, I'm give -2 for my question. How does it work? Why is it showing -5? I think the voting is spitefully motivated,

I would like to ask a more general question on what I wrote in that question, but I'm told that I can't for two days. That seems very extreme.

Comment: It seems that your question has not well received by community. Read [ask] and visit related question on [downvote](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/277) and on [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/260388). p.s. your question looks too long, make it clear and to the point.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the admins or moderators do not have anything in stopping you from posting a new question for two days. It is done by automatic filter for some users. Some of the symptoms are:

- users who can't be bothered to form sentences
- users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
- users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

Before you have posted your question, you posted a few answers which were deleted as rude and abusive. A couple of them were comments and unclear. There is a [**Code of conduct**](/conduct) which applies everywhere. **You need to be respectful towards everyone while posting questions and answers**.

When it comes to your question, I am one of the downvoters because it is unclear what you are asking, it contains too many sub questions comparing with other religions. *The very first line of your question contains a word "vicious" referring to Christianity and Islam*. That is not at all okay. Using rude words can not only prevent you from posting new questions and answers, it may also get you suspended if the writing style continues . We know nothing about you to hold grudges and target voting at you. It would be totally better for you if you use lower tone (both here on meta and main site). As said already, you may get bans for posting poor content that too with that tone.

Though this is Hinduism Stack Exchange, it doesn't mean it is only exclusive for Hindus and all other religions can be censured.

You have to edit your current (and deleted) contributions more clearly using a lower tone and if the system feels they are okay, then the ban may be lifted. Even though you may feel others are not good, we are actually nice. I hope you are also nice *human being* and will improve your questions and answers.

- Read [How do I ask a good question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

You may check your reputation audit at [Reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/reputation) after you get a reputation of 10 and also in "Reputation" tab in activity of your profile. See [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). From that page,

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> question is voted up: +5
>   answer is voted up: +10
>   answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
>   suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
>   bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
>   one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
>       site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
>
> **You lose reputation when:**
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

You lost reputation because your question and answer is deleted.